# UI not showing up in fragment (RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I created a fragment with RecyclerView with two View Type (Header of the recycler,The rows)
and the model for the recycler so simple it is about product stuff,
finally the adapter with two holder types for the recycler.
 Now I tried to run the emulator calling the fragment but the Ui inside the recycler not showing up,
I was working with this process to create recyclerView with many View types many times and it just working fine.
but now the UI not showing up and no error appears .

the Fragment code

```
public class SelectedCategoryFragment extends Fragment implements SelectedCtategoryAdapter.onRowListener {
private RecyclerView productRecyclerView;
private ArrayList<SelectedCategoryModel> categoryModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public SelectedCategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_selected_category, container, false);
    initialize(v);
    setUpProductRecycler();

    return v;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void setUpProductRecycler() {
    productRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slide_menu_divider));

    productRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    SelectedCtategoryAdapter selectedCtategoryAdapter = new SelectedCtategoryAdapter(productList(), this);

    productRecyclerView.setAdapter(selectedCtategoryAdapter);
}

private ArrayList<SelectedCategoryModel> productList() {

    SelectedCategoryModel p1 = new SelectedCategoryModel("category Name", "", "", "", R.drawable.sweets);
    categoryModelArrayList.add(p1);

    SelectedCategoryModel p2 = new SelectedCategoryModel("sweets", "sweets1", "30", "3", R.drawable.logo);
    categoryModelArrayList.add(p2);

    SelectedCategoryModel p3 = new SelectedCategoryModel("category Name", "sweets2", "44", "", R.drawable.sweets);
    categoryModelArrayList.add(p3);

    SelectedCategoryModel p4 = new SelectedCategoryModel("category Name", "sweets3", "88", "", R.drawable.sweets);
    categoryModelArrayList.add(p4);

    SelectedCategoryModel p5 = new SelectedCategoryModel("category Name", "sweets4", "101", "", R.drawable.sweets);
    categoryModelArrayList.add(p5);

    SelectedCategoryModel p6 = new SelectedCategoryModel("category Name", "sweets5", "45", "", R.drawable.sweets);
    categoryModelArrayList.add(p6);

    SelectedCategoryModel p7 = new SelectedCategoryModel("category Name", "sweets6", "90", "", R.drawable.sweets);
    categoryModelArrayList.add(p7);

    return categoryModelArrayList;
}

private void initialize(View v) {
    productRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.product_recyclerview);
}

@Override
public void onRowClick(int position) {

}
}
```

---

```
**the model**
```

---

```
public class SelectedCategoryModel {

private String productName,productDesc,productRate,deliveryCost;
private int productPhoto;

public SelectedCategoryModel(String productName, String productDesc, String productRate, String deliveryCost, int productPhoto) {
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productDesc = productDesc;
    this.productRate = productRate;
    this.deliveryCost = deliveryCost;
    this.productPhoto = productPhoto;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public String getProductDesc() {
    return productDesc;
}

public void setProductDesc(String productDesc) {
    this.productDesc = productDesc;
}

public String getProductRate() {
    return productRate;
}

public void setProductRate(String productRate) {
    this.productRate = productRate;
}

public String getDeliveryCost() {
    return deliveryCost;
}

public void setDeliveryCost(String deliveryCost) {
    this.deliveryCost = deliveryCost;
}

public int getProductPhoto() {
    return productPhoto;
}

public void setProductPhoto(int productPhoto) {
    this.productPhoto = productPhoto;
}
}
```

---

adapter

---

```
public class SelectedCtategoryAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
    private static final int header_type = 0;
    private static final int row_type = 1;
    private ArrayList<SelectedCategoryModel>arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    public int index = -1;
    public SelectedCtategoryAdapter.onRowListener onRowListener;

    public SelectedCtategoryAdapter() {
    }

public SelectedCtategoryAdapter(ArrayList<SelectedCategoryModel> arrayList, SelectedCtategoryAdapter.onRowListener onRowListener) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.onRowListener = onRowListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder recyclerViewHolder;
    if (viewType == header_type) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
        recyclerViewHolder = new HeaderHolder(view, viewType, onRowListener);
        return recyclerViewHolder;


    } else if (viewType == row_type) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_items, parent, false);
        recyclerViewHolder = new RowHolder(view, viewType, onRowListener);
        return recyclerViewHolder;


    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,final int position) {

    if (holder instanceof SelectedCtategoryAdapter.HeaderHolder) {
        SelectedCtategoryAdapter.HeaderHolder headerHolder = (SelectedCtategoryAdapter.HeaderHolder) holder;
        headerHolder.header.setBackgroundResource(arrayList.get(position).getProductPhoto());

    } else if (holder instanceof SelectedCtategoryAdapter.RowHolder) {
        SelectedCtategoryAdapter.RowHolder rowHolder = (SelectedCtategoryAdapter.RowHolder) holder;
        Log.i("position>>", position + "");
        rowHolder.productName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getProductName());
        rowHolder.productDesc.setText(arrayList.get(position).getProductDesc());
        rowHolder.productRate.setText(arrayList.get(position).getProductRate());
        rowHolder.deliveryCost.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDeliveryCost());
        rowHolder.productPhoto.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getProductPhoto());
        rowHolder.categoryProductRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                onRowListener.onRowClick(position);
                index = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        if (index == position) {
            rowHolder.categoryProductRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A4CD39"));
        } else {
            rowHolder.categoryProductRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#90a3a3a3"));

        }
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}


public class HeaderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    SelectedCtategoryAdapter.onRowListener onRowListener;
    TextView headerTitle;
    LinearLayout header;
    public HeaderHolder(View v, int viewtype, SelectedCtategoryAdapter.onRowListener onRowListener) {
        super(v);
        headerTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.category_Header_title);
        header = v.findViewById(R.id.category_Header);
        this.onRowListener = onRowListener;
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onRowListener.onRowClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}


public class RowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView productPhoto;
    TextView productName,productDesc,productRate,deliveryCost;
    SelectedCtategoryAdapter.onRowListener onRowListener;
    LinearLayout categoryProductRow;

    public RowHolder(View v, int viewtype, SelectedCtategoryAdapter.onRowListener onRowListener) {
        super(v);
        productPhoto = v.findViewById(R.id.product_photo_1);
        productName = v.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        productDesc = v.findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
        productRate = v.findViewById(R.id.product_rate_1);
        deliveryCost = v.findViewById(R.id.delivery_cost);
        categoryProductRow = v.findViewById(R.id.category_product_row);
        this.onRowListener = onRowListener;
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onRowListener.onRowClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return header_type;
    }
  else {
        return row_type;
    }
}

public interface onRowListener {
    void onRowClick(int position);
}
```

}

---

may I have your time to check what is the issue over here ?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think change to `getItemCount` in adapter may help

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will never forgot this,I was totally out of focus.